# LUIS is not responding Test in Web Chat and chatbot working fine from Emulator and directline

Tags: botframework, web-chat, azure-language-understanding

We are facing issue in Azure chatbot, LUIS is not responding in **Test in Web Chat** on Azure. Chatbot is working fine Emulator and integration with direct line. My client is testing always from Azure so it is some critical issue for us. We are using Standard LUIS runtime subscription. It would be great if someone can help us. I did below trouble shooting steps.

1. Subscription key for standard plan and verify keys , it is correct.
2. Re-deployed
3. See application Insights error code is 400 only when i run it from Azure **Test in Web Chat**

Comment: You need to verify Microsoft App Id & Password and also Luis published url because it look like bad request.

Comment: hi @RajeeshMenoth I checked all things again and  still same problem,

Comment: Test the published url in the browser tab and if it working then it's your code issue.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth , Code is working perfect for other channel like Emulator, Direct Line and till last week, webchat was also working suddenly webchat get stopped.

Comment: What about today ? Is it working or all are down ? Then you can check the application insight error log. If you are using free tier then check the request limit,etc

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth today, it is not working in ** Test in Web chat**  , it is working for all except web chat,  I am using standard not free tire and  error code for web chat is 400 in application insights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235148/discussion-between-rajeesh-menoth-and-upendra).

Comment: hi @Nikitha-MSFT  could you please check it with your team ?  Actually my clients is testing chatbot from Azure.

Comment: Hi @RajeeshMenoth , thanks for responding but I have already done these troubleshooting  steps.  It is working properly after integration and hosting  with direct line  but the problem is " It is not working inside Azure Test in Web Chat  window " I hope you got it and AppId and password both are correct otherwise it wasn't work in different channels. I think this is from MS Azure end. interesting part is embedded code of  webchat channel is also working  but same chatbot is not working inside Azure portal when i tried to test it from there.

Comment: Then better to create a support ticket to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I opened MS support ticket for this issue and find same issue was running at support team side as well. There were no code and configuration change after some time it suddenly start functioning.

Thanks